# Outstanding medical bills in the US - Will I be held at the border?

Tags: customs-and-immigration

So my question is definitely a duplicate, but the answers on similar questions to mine are 3-5 years old.

I just wanted to be sure that because how much time has passed, maybe the US has changed its policies and I just don't want to get caught up in that if that's the case.

If anybody can verify one of the answers I read in a similar question "Immigration officials do not have access to your debt information, they only have access to immigration info provided on visa forms or entry forms or court actions against you (and this later is only for serious offences, not minor things like parking tickets)."

Not that I'm trying to avoid paying, I just want to make sure I can still travel to the US even though the payments are ongoing through insurance.

Also, for what it's worth, I just received a 1-year P1 visa to the US.

Comment: When were the services rendered?  You have a pending insurance claim?

Answer (score 9):

First, until there has been a court judgment against you, the collection of the debt is a private matter between you and lender and the State cannot enforce it. Not every debt is paid in full in the USA - some debts are forgiven or written off, and some are invalidated by courts.

And indeed immigration officials do not have access to your private debt information. And even if they had, [it is not part of CBP duties](https://www.cbp.gov/careers/frontline-careers/cbpo/duties) to enforce private debt collection.

Comment: That link does not really support your claim, CBP officials surely are concerned about more than just what is written in their job ad.

Comment: "And even if they had, it is not part of CBP duties to enforce private debt collection." No, but it is CBP's job to deny entry to most types of nonimmigrant visitors if they fail to overcome the presumption of immigrant intent, and any negative information that comes to their attention can affect their determination.

Comment: @user102008 I can hardly see a connection between having an outstanding debt and immigration intent.